# NDSolve for a 4th order differential equation with boundary condition at Infinity

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I would like to solve a 4th-order differential equation of the form:

$\partial^2_x\left(\,\frac{\partial^2_x\rho}{\rho}-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial_x\rho}{\rho}\right)^2\right)= -2\lambda\rho$

with boundary conditions defined at $\pm∞$:

$\rho(x=∞)=0,\rho'(x=∞)=0,\rho''(x=∞)=0$ and $\rho'''(x=∞)=0$

I tried to use NDsolve but im not so familiar with that... so i'm not sure if it is the good way to do. Hereafter for $\lambda=1/2$:

```
NDSolveValue[{D[(D[r[x], {x, 2}]/r[x]) - ((D[r[x], x]/r[x])^2)/2, {x, 
 2}] == -r[x], 
  r[-Infinity] == r'[-Infinity] == r''[-Infinity] == 
   r'''[-Infinity] == 0}, ', {x, -2, 2}]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Thank you !
Eru

Comment: Include your try too...

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Here's a solution: $\rho\equiv 0$.

Comment: Thank you for the reply guys ! Im looking for solution different from the case $\rho=0$ :p !

Comment: `DSolve` doesn't find a general solution of this non-linear equation. But if a solution is not unique there's a problem anyway. As a possible variant one can try a change $y=1/x$. At least the initial conditions will be at the origin.

Comment: 1. What does `y`do in your code? Is it a 1D or 2D equation? 2. Do you fix a numeric value of lambda? 3. I think I have an approach that might be helpful for you. Have a look at the paper  Alexei Boulbitch, Yury M. Gufan, and Alexander L. Korzhenevskii, Phys. Rev. E 96, 013005 (2017), where in one of the appendices the approach is explained.

Comment: The text states, "with boundary conditions defined at ±∞", but the boundary conditions immediately following are at `+Infinity` only, and the code at `-Infinity` only.  Which is correct?

Answer (score 1):

You need more reasonable boundary conditions to solve this one.  First of all, `NDSolve` blows up whenever `r -> 0`, so you cannot start out bc's with `r = 0`.

Start with the ode

```
ode = Simplify[D[D[r[x], {x, 2}]/r[x] - (1/2)*(D[r[x], x]/r[x])^2, {x, 2}] + r[x]] == 0;
```

Simpler with out the denominator.

```
ode = ode r[x]^4;
```

We can approximate your bc's with a big negative number for `-Infinity` and a very small number other than `0` for the starting value of `r`.

```
Clear[r]
limit = 10^7

NDSolve[{ode, r[-limit] == 10^-15, r'[-limit] == 0, r''[-limit] == 0, 
   r'''[-limit] == 0}, r[x], {x, -limit, limit}] // Flatten;

r[x_] = r[x] /. %

Plot[r[x], {x, -limit, limit}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

The solution is pretty much `0` all the way, which makes sense since r starts out close to `0` and the derivatives are `0` and there is not anything in the ode to change it from `0`.  So let's try saner bc's.

Clear[r];
limit = 10;

```
NDSolve[{ode, r[0] == 1, r'[0] == 0, r''[0] == 0, r'''[0] == 0}, 
  r[x], {x, -limit, limit}, MaxSteps -> 50000] // Flatten;

r[x_] = r[x] /. %;

Plot[r[x], {x, -2.85398, 2.85398}]
```

[image]

The solution stops at approx x +-2.85, because that is where `r` goes to `0`.

It looks like the curve is asymptotically approaching `0` which may extend to +-Infinity.  I can't prove it because `NDSolve` blows up when `r -> 0`.

An extended look at the curve is supports the asymptotic behavior, but of course does not prove it.  My guess is that this solution is 0 and flat at x +-Infinity being the conditions you want. If I choose bc's other than at `x = 0`, I get the same curve shifted along the x axis.  A higher value for the starting value of `r` narrows the curve, but we get the same asymptotic look.

[image]

Choosing the bc's at + or -Infinity, besides making NDSolve fail,  probably makes the solution non unique, since many cases seem to satisfy the bc's you chose.

Answer (score 1):

The ode has symmetrical solution `r[x]==r[-x]` so it is sufficient to solve the ode in the range `x \[Element] [0, \[Infinity]]` with none vanishing b.c. `r[0]==\[Rho], r''[0]==\[CurlyKappa]`

```
solu[\[Rho]_?NumericQ, \[CurlyKappa]_?NumericQ, lim_?NumericQ] := 
NDSolveValue[{ode, r[0] == \[Rho], r'[0] == 0,r''[0] == \[CurlyKappa], r'''[0] == 0, 
WhenEvent[r[x] == .0001  , xE = x; "StopIntegration"]}, {r,xE}, {x, 0, lim}]
```

The simulation is terminated ( `WhenEvent`) if r[x] becomes small enough.

For given parameters the solution (for example `solu[.5, -.2, 150.]`)  can be displayed

```
Plot[Evaluate[#[[1]][x]], {x, 0, Evaluate[#[[2]]]},PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 1}, All, Full}[[4]],AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, AxesLabel -> {x, r[x]}] &[solu[.5, -.2, 150.]]
```

[image]